# JSON-LD created by javascript is not structured data

Tags: javascript, html, json, seo

I am trying to generate json-ld structured data automatically with javascript for my website. Everything was fine until I checked from the [tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/), the json-ld code generated in javascript didn't show up on the test table. When I proceed to view source on chrome it do not display the json-ld code.

You can see it live [here](https://www.nhadatsonnghia.com/search/label/mua-ban-nha-dat-go-vap)

The code is blow

```
<script id='myJSONID' type='application/ld+json'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$('#myJSONID').text(function() {
    return JSON.stringify({
        "@context":"https://schema.org",
        "@type":"Review",
        "author": {
            "@type":"Person",
            "name":"Nhà Gò Vấp đẹp",
            "sameAs":"https://www.blogger.com/profile/14170245093404020455"
        },
        "url": "<data:blog.canonicalUrl/>",
        "datePublished": "<data:post.dateHeader/>",
        "publisher": {
            "@type":"Organization",
            "name":"" + document.title,
            "sameAs":"<data:blog.homepageUrl/>"
        },
        "description":"" + document.getElementsByName("description")[0].content,
        "inLanguage":"vi",
        "itemReviewed": {
            "@type":"Product",
            "name": "<data:blog.pageName/>",
            "description":"" + document.getElementsByName("description")[0].content,
            "sameAs": "<data:blog.canonicalUrl/>",
            "image": "<data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl/>",
            "aggregateRating": {
                "@type": "AggregateRating",
                "ratingValue": "5",
                "bestRating": "5",
                "ratingCount": "20"
             }
        }
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

I want to ask people to see if I have done anything wrong in the javascript code above? And if so, why doesn't google recognize this json-ld data?

Thanks in advance!